# How to display all record row from database table into a table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html-table

I'm trying to made a table which can get database table value all row record. I've made it and I can do it but the data record just showing one data from the record database table, and it always looping the record value to the right while I clicked the button for showing the record into the table. Does anyone know what wrong with my code here?

This is the php, jquery and the html script, and the screenshot of the page:

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ajaxButton").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "employee.php",
            success: function(data) {
                var list = JSON.parse(data);
                var tr = "";
                $.each(list, function(i, v) {
                    tr = +"<tr>";
                    tr += "<td>" + v['no'] + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + v['sensor1'] + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + v['sensor2'] + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + v['sensor3'] + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + v['sensor4'] + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + v['sensor5'] + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + v['sensor6'] + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + v['sensor7'] + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + v['sensor8'] + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + v['sensor9'] + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + v['sensor10'] + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + v['sensor11'] + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + v['sensor12'] + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + v['ambien'] + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + v['average'] + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + v['deffiasi'] + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + v['status'] + "</td>";
                    tr += "</tr>";

                });
                $("#table_s tbody").append(tr);
            }
        });
    });
});
            row += '<td>' + data.rows[i].date + '</td>';
            row += '<td>' + data.rows[i].company + '</td>';
            row += '<td>' + data.rows[i].location + '</td>';
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="table_s" id="table_s" class="table_s">
    <table id="table_s" class="table_s"cellspacing='0' class="js-serial" border="2">
        <thead>

      <tr>
                <th><center>No.</center></th>
                <th><center>S1</center></th>
                <th><center>S2</center></th>
                <th><center>S3</center></th>
                <th><center>S4</center></th>
                <th><center>S5</center></th>
                <th><center>S6</center></th>
                <th><center>S7</center></th>
                <th><center>S8</center></th>
                <th><center>S9</center></th>
                <th><center>S10</center></th>
                <th><center>S11</center></th>
                <th><center>S12</center></th>
                <th><center>Ambien</center></th>
                <th><center>Average</center></th>
                <th><center>Deff</center></th>
                <th><center>Status</center></th>
      </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
          </tr>

      </tbody>
      </table>
<input type="button" value="Click Here" id="ajaxButton"/>

</body>
</html>
```

```html
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","silo");

if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}


// Data for Titik1
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM termocouple");
$rows = array();

while($tmp= mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $rows[] = $tmp;


}

echo json_encode($rows);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: If you're writing new code, **_please_ don't use the `mysql_*` functions**. They are old and broken, were deprecated in PHP 5.5 (which is so old it no longer even receives security updates), and completely removed in PHP 7. Use [`PDO`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`mysqli_*`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) with _prepared statements_ and _parameter binding_ instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/354577 for details.

Comment: @Chris i've done editing the code. i use mysqli now

Comment: `tr = +"<tr>";` Makes that the tr variable is equal NaN as that + operator will convert string to number, which is  converted to NaN (not a number) and then stored to tr variable, so you're missing opening <tr> tag in result. Saying that, `tr = +"<tr>"` is not equal to `tr += "<tr>"`

Comment: then which one i must use? tr = + "<tr>"  or tr +="<tr>"?

Comment: im sorry.. im new at json. can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

You should append tr within the loop.

```
success: function(data){
  var list = JSON.parse(data);
  for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    var tr = "<tr>";
    tr += "<td>"+list[i]['no']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>"+list[i]['sensor1']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>"+list[i]['sensor2']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>"+list[i]['sensor3']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>"+list[i]['sensor4']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>"+list[i]['sensor5']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>"+list[i]['sensor6']+"</td>";
    tr += "</tr>";
    $("#table_s tbody").append(tr);
  }
}
```

Comment: it still showing one data only and keep looping making the tr result to the right place like my image that i've upload

Comment: Reference this fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/4wqowkbh/1/).It shows multiple row in table.